# Как правильно создать связь моделей Yii

Tags: yii, framework

```
'categories' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category', 'subcat_user(user, category)'),
```

Это связь в моей модельке, сейчас происходит связь многие ко многим по ид юзера и категории. А как мне сделать связь не к ид юзера а к другому полю юзера? например city_id

Comment: Если я правильно помню Yii 1, в этом случае связь будет на стороне City.

Comment: нет вы не поняли мне нужно именно многи ко многи и что-бы в этой же модельке, только не к ид юзера а к другому полю модельки

Comment: Нет, я-то прекрасно понял. Связь многие-ко-многим просто через поле в таблице/модели (без промежуточной таблицы) невозможна.

Comment: Это я знаю просто хотел указать другое поле так как нужно было получить связь для поиска пришлось применить оператор through

Comment: Зачем вам through, если там есть MANY_MANY?

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос так 
моделька профиля
`'Users_relations'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'id_user'),
'categories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Category', 'category', 'through' => 'Users_relations.userSub'),`
моделька юзера которая и была связана с категориями

```
 'userSub' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SubcatUser', 'user'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю надо сделать несколько связей для каждого поля, либо в CDBCriteria динамически указывать on

```
$criteria->with = array(
    'on' => 'categories.key1 = subcat_user.key1 AND categories.key2 = subcat_user.key2'
);
```